# Calling xcodebuild from Swift command line tool fails

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, xcodebuild, nstask

I'm writing simple swift command line tool application that automates some of my iOS Dev work. Everything is working except one thing - calling xcodebuild script.

My method looks like this:

```
func runTest(deviceName: String, os: String) {
        killAllSimulators()
        let sdk = "iphonesimulator"
        let destination = "platform=iOS Simulator,name=" + deviceName + ",OS=" + os
        let arguments = ["-workspace", workspace, "-scheme", scheme, "-sdk", sdk, "-destination", destination, "test"]
        executor.executeCommand("xcodebuild", arguments: arguments)
    }
```

deviceName is equal to "iPhone 4s", os is equal to "9.0", workspace and scheme variables are properly set.

My execute command has simple implementation:

```
func executeCommand(command: String, arguments: [String]) -> NSString?  {
        _ = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().processIdentifier
        let pipe = NSPipe()
        let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading

        let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/" + command
        task.arguments = arguments
        task.standardOutput = pipe

        task.launch()
        let data = fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.closeFile()

        return NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
```

i got error that test failed because cdtool cannot compile. Thats very weird because exactly the same script called from terminal works..

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to quote that device name if it contains spaces.

Comment: println() destination and arguments so you can see exactly the commands, that is basic debugging. My guess is the space in "iPhone 4s" is the problem.

Comment: I also thought `xcodebuild` cared about *current directory* as well.

Comment: destination parameter is one string so it is: -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone4s,OS=9.0'. In that case there is no problem with quotes

Comment: Got this message: dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_OS_object
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib
 in /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
cdtool exited abnormally

Comment: The question has: "iPhone 4s", the comment has: "name=iPhone4s", the name is not the same.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was my mistake but after correction nothing changes. Even if i run script that has hardcoded arguments if fails. The same script that was executed from terminal runs well.

Comment: @MichalMoskala Any updates here? I encountered the same error when archiving my project...

Comment: @Itachi unfortunately I haven't fixed it