# Xcode continuous integration in Jenkins failing

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

Xcode continuous integration in Jenkins failing. This was working fine till last week ,suddenly it is failing with given reasons.

Logs.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/cdtool
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /usr/local/lib/libwep: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
        /usr/local/lib/libwep: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
        /usr/local/lib/libwep: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2017-08-27 21:45:00.073 momc[53458:1052972] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is empty; did you forget to send -finishEncoding to the NSKeyedArchiver?
cdtool invalid hashes:
<http://10.1.171.101:8080/job/IOS/ws/MYPro/Product> Resources/Core Data/CoredataBCCD.xcdatamodeld/COREDATA1BCCD.xcdatamodel:: error: cdtool cannot compile

The following build commands failed:  
DataModelCompile /Users/damodarnamala/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPRro-cnfnpyxuorapbjaqyheoydybiocw/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MYAPPNAME/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MYAPPNAME.app/ Product\ Resources/Core\ Data/COREDATA1BCCD.xcdatamodeld
(1 failure)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
```

Comment: Are you trying to save Core Data Transformable?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872557/xcodebuild-cdtool-cannot-compile-datamodelcompile-path-to-coredatamodel-xcdat

Comment: No, not building, it throwing compile time error.
cp: /Users/username/Documents//Trunk/CoreDataFiles/*.momd: No such file or directory

Comment: May be your path is wrong. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536414/cant-find-momd-file-core-data-problems

Comment: Try this to get the path of momd file. `if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: nil, ofType:"momd") { print("Path \(path)")}`